# Как сохранить JSP в переменную типа String?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Использую SPRING.
Мне нужно заполнить шаблон в JSP и вернуть его в переменную.

При этом, операция производится не в контроллере, а в сервисе.

Как это правильно сделать ?

Comment: Что значит "вернуть его в переменную"?

Comment: Значит, что у меня есть переменная типа стринг и я в нее хочу сохранить вью в виде строки, чтобы потом вложить в почтовик, для отправки в качестве сообщения. (В этой вьюхе будут формироваться таблицы)